# Counter too large ERROR when it shouldn't

Tags: subfloats

My Latex document suddenly stopped compiling and raising the "! LaTeX Error: Counter too large." error for no apparent reason. It compiled before, with the same amount of figures and subfigures, but even by erasing the things I added since the last time it compiled, it just doesn't work anymore.

I know what generally causes this error => when captioning more than 26 subfigures, it runs out of letter to label the subfigures and throws this error. This is not my case. My largest figure only has 8 subfigures so I don't know why it doesn't work.

Here's part of my code (more figures come before this):

```
\documentclass[11pt, oneside]{Thesis} % The default font size and one-sided printing (no margin offsets)

\graphicspath{{./Pictures/}} % Specifies the directory where pictures are stored

\usepackage[T1]{fontenc}
\usepackage{mathtools}  % loads »amsmath«
\usepackage{amsmath}
\usepackage{physics}
\usepackage{float}

\usepackage{tabularx}
\usepackage{adjustbox}
\usepackage[english]{babel}
\usepackage[table]{xcolor}
\usepackage{tabularx}
%\usepackage{showframe} % for demo
\usepackage{lmodern}
\usepackage{microtype}
\usepackage{ragged2e}
\usepackage{lua-visual-debug}

\usepackage{placeins}
\usepackage{multirow}
\usepackage{graphicx} 
\usepackage{caption} 
\usepackage{subcaption}
\usepackage[square, numbers, comma, sort&compress]{natbib} 

\usepackage{booktabs}
%\usepackage[table,xcdraw]{xcolor}

\hypersetup{urlcolor=blue, colorlinks=true} % Colors hyperlinks in blue - change to black if annoying
\title{\ttitle} % Defines the thesis title - don't touch this

\begin{document}

\FloatBarrier
\section{Influence of solid exits}
%compare 5wg and 6wg. REG and SIDE sections, velocity vectors, turbulence, velocity contours?, ... Explain "vortex air-wall" in both, and why it's a clear advantage in 6wg.

\begin{table}[h]
\centering
\hspace*{-2cm}\makebox[\linewidth][c]{%
\begin{tabularx}{1.4\textwidth}{c*{2}{>{\centering\arraybackslash}X}@{}}
&   \begin{subfigure}{\hsize} 
        \includegraphics[width=\hsize]{SE_5wg_REG_VV}
        \caption{In-plane velocity vectors [m/s] - 5-wheels geometry}
        \medskip
    \end{subfigure}
&   \begin{subfigure}{\hsize} 
        \includegraphics[width=\hsize]{SE_6wg_REG_VV}
        \caption{In-plane velocity vectors [m/s]] - 6-wheels geometry}
        \medskip
    \end{subfigure}     \\
&   \begin{subfigure}{\hsize} 
        \includegraphics[width=\hsize]{SE_5wg_REG_VVz}
        \caption{In-plane velocity vectors [m/s] - 5-wheels geometry close-up}
        \medskip
    \end{subfigure}
&   \begin{subfigure}{\hsize} 
        \includegraphics[width=\hsize]{SE_6wg_REG_VVz}
        \caption{In-plane velocity vectors [m/s] - 6-wheels geometry close-up}
        \medskip
    \end{subfigure}  \\
&   \begin{subfigure}{\hsize} 
        \includegraphics[width=\hsize]{SE_5wg_REG_TANz}
        \caption{Tangential velocity contours [m/s] - 5-wheels geometry close-up}
        \medskip
    \end{subfigure}
&   \begin{subfigure}{\hsize} 
        \includegraphics[width=\hsize]{SE_6wg_REG_TANz}
        \caption{Tangential velocity contours [m/s] - 6-wheels geometry close-up}
        \medskip
    \end{subfigure}  \\
    &   \begin{subfigure}{\hsize} 
        \includegraphics[width=\hsize]{SE_5wg_REG_TURBz}
        \caption{Subgrid turbulent viscosity ratio [kg/m.s] - 5-wheels geometry close-up}
        \medskip
    \end{subfigure}
&   \begin{subfigure}{\hsize} 
        \includegraphics[width=\hsize]{SE_6wg_REG_TURBz}
        \caption{Subgrid turbulent viscosity ratio [kg/m.s] - 6-wheels geometry close-up}
        \medskip
    \end{subfigure}  \\
\end{tabularx}}
\caption{Influence of the solid exits: 5-wheels geometry (left) and 6-wheels geometry (right)}
\label{solid_exits}
\end{table}


\FloatBarrier
\section{Influence of chimneys}
%Chimneys as turbulence creators?
%Chimney diameter? => central reflux! show in both 5wg and 6wg!
%Possible solution => conic chimneys, show with 6wg.

\begin{table}[h]
\centering
\hspace*{-2cm}\makebox[\linewidth][c]{%
\begin{tabularx}{1.4\textwidth}{c*{2}{>{\centering\arraybackslash}X}@{}}
&   \begin{subfigure}{\hsize} 
        \includegraphics[width=\hsize]{CH_5wg_REG_VV}
        \caption{In-plane velocity vectors [m/s] - 5-wheels geometry}
        \medskip
    \end{subfigure}
&   \begin{subfigure}{\hsize} 
        \includegraphics[width=\hsize]{CH_6wg_REG_VV}
        \caption{In-plane velocity vectors [m/s]] - 6-wheels geometry}
        \medskip
    \end{subfigure}     \\
&   \begin{subfigure}{\hsize} 
        \includegraphics[width=\hsize]{CH_5wg_REG_VVz2}
        \caption{In-plane velocity vectors [m/s] - 5-wheels geometry close-up}
        \medskip
    \end{subfigure}
&   \begin{subfigure}{\hsize} 
        \includegraphics[width=\hsize]{CH_6wg_REG_VVz2}
        \caption{In-plane velocity vectors [m/s] - 6-wheels geometry close-up}
        \medskip
    \end{subfigure}  \\
&   \begin{subfigure}{\hsize} 
        \includegraphics[width=\hsize]{CH_5wg_REG_AXIz}
        \caption{Axial velocity contours [m/s] - 5-wheels geometry close-up}
        \medskip
    \end{subfigure}
&   \begin{subfigure}{\hsize} 
        \includegraphics[width=\hsize]{CH_6wg_REG_AXIz}
        \caption{Axial velocity contours [m/s] - 6-wheels geometry close-up}
        \medskip
    \end{subfigure}  \\
    &   \begin{subfigure}{\hsize} 
        \includegraphics[width=\hsize]{CH_5wg_REG_TURBz2}
        \caption{Subgrid turbulent viscosity ratio [kg/m.s] - 5-wheels geometry close-up}
        \medskip
    \end{subfigure}
&   \begin{subfigure}{\hsize} 
        \includegraphics[width=\hsize]{CH_6wg_REG_TURBz2}
        \caption{Subgrid turbulent viscosity ratio [kg/m.s] - 6-wheels geometry close-up}
        \medskip
    \end{subfigure}  \\
\end{tabularx}}
\caption{Influence of the chimneys: 5-wheels geometry (left) and 6-wheels geometry (right)}
\label{chimneys}
\end{table}

\end{document}
```

I know I didn't used the most straightforward method to create my tables, and I could have used a minipage for my subfigures instead. But if possible I would like to keep those "tables with subfigures" as they are (with minor changes if necessary to fix the problem ofc).

Comment: Welcome to TeX.SX! Can I suggest that you try to selectively comment out lines of code so you can cut what you have down to a [minimal working example](http://meta.tex.stackexchange.com/questions/228/) . Almost certainly most of your code is not relevant to your problem so you should try to distill the example down to what is actually important. This will help us help you - and you might even solve the problem by yourself in the process!

Comment: I  adopt your MWE in form., which I can compile (your image replace with `example-image` from `graphicx` package and instead of `Thesis` I use `book`) and remove doubled packages. I don't get any error your, but caption numbering system doesn't work and counting of subimages is not reset in new figures.

Comment: What's the purpose of `tabularx`?

Comment: @egreg: Not sure if it's necessary here, but I copied the table structure from somewhere else in my thesis which used tabularx. Since it worked I didn't change it.

Comment: @Zarko: Yes that's what I found since then, the subfigures counter doesn't reset :/. I tried to solve it with \setcounter{table}{0} or \setcounter{subfigure}{0}, but for whatever reason that doesn't work.

Comment: Since you're loading the package `lua-visual-debug`, I assume you want to compile the program under LuaLaTeX rather than, say, pdfLaTeX. I encounter no problems compiling your program under LuaLaTeX, by the way. A separate issue: The Internet is crawling with document classes called `Thesis` -- what's the source of `Thesis.cls` that you are using?

Comment: A separate comment: What's the purpose of having `subfigure` environments inside a `table` environment? I'd aim for consistency: Either make the outer float type a `figure`, or use `subtable` as the float type for the inner floats.

Comment: @Mico: I found it on this link http://www.latextemplates.com/template/masters-doctoral-thesis

Answer (score 1):

I get no error and also the reset of subfigure numbering if I remove `tabularx`, that's probably the cause for the issue.

You simply don't need it just for setting multiple subfigures.

I also changed `Thesis` to `book`, as it's impossible to know what class you're loading.

```
\PassOptionsToPackage{demo}{graphicx} % just for this example
\documentclass[11pt, oneside]{book} % The default font size and one-sided printing (no margin offsets)

\usepackage[T1]{fontenc}
\usepackage{mathtools}  % loads »amsmath«
\usepackage{amsmath}
\usepackage{physics}
\usepackage{float}

\usepackage{adjustbox}
\usepackage[english]{babel}
\usepackage[table]{xcolor}
%\usepackage{showframe} % for demo
\usepackage{lmodern}
\usepackage{microtype}
\usepackage{ragged2e}
\usepackage{lua-visual-debug}

\usepackage{placeins}
\usepackage{multirow}
\usepackage{graphicx} 
\usepackage{caption} 
\usepackage{subcaption}
\usepackage[square, numbers, comma, sort&compress]{natbib} 

\usepackage{booktabs}
%\usepackage[table,xcdraw]{xcolor}
\usepackage{hyperref}

\hypersetup{urlcolor=blue, colorlinks=true} % Colors hyperlinks in blue - change to black if annoying

\graphicspath{{./Pictures/}} % Specifies the directory where pictures are stored

\title{\ttitle} % Defines the thesis title - don't touch this

\begin{document}

\FloatBarrier
\section{Influence of solid exits}
%compare 5wg and 6wg. REG and SIDE sections, velocity vectors, turbulence, velocity contours?, ... Explain "vortex air-wall" in both, and why it's a clear advantage in 6wg.

\begin{table}[htp]
\centering
\makebox[\columnwidth][c]{%
  \begin{minipage}{1.4\linewidth}
  \centering
    \begin{subfigure}[t]{.49\textwidth} 
        \includegraphics[width=\textwidth,height=2cm]{SE_5wg_REG_VV}
        \caption{In-plane velocity vectors [m/s] - 5-wheels geometry}
        \medskip
    \end{subfigure}\hfill
    \begin{subfigure}[t]{.49\textwidth} 
        \includegraphics[width=\textwidth,height=2cm]{SE_6wg_REG_VV}
        \caption{In-plane velocity vectors [m/s]] - 6-wheels geometry}
        \medskip
    \end{subfigure}     \\
    \begin{subfigure}[t]{.49\textwidth} 
        \includegraphics[width=\textwidth,height=2cm]{SE_5wg_REG_VVz}
        \caption{In-plane velocity vectors [m/s] - 5-wheels geometry close-up}
        \medskip
    \end{subfigure}\hfill
    \begin{subfigure}[t]{.49\textwidth} 
        \includegraphics[width=\textwidth,height=2cm]{SE_6wg_REG_VVz}
        \caption{In-plane velocity vectors [m/s] - 6-wheels geometry close-up}
        \medskip
    \end{subfigure}  \\
    \begin{subfigure}[t]{.49\textwidth} 
        \includegraphics[width=\textwidth,height=2cm]{SE_5wg_REG_TANz}
        \caption{Tangential velocity contours [m/s] - 5-wheels geometry close-up}
        \medskip
    \end{subfigure}\hfill
    \begin{subfigure}[t]{.49\textwidth} 
        \includegraphics[width=\textwidth,height=2cm]{SE_6wg_REG_TANz}
        \caption{Tangential velocity contours [m/s] - 6-wheels geometry close-up}
        \medskip
    \end{subfigure}  \\
    \begin{subfigure}[t]{.49\textwidth} 
        \includegraphics[width=\textwidth,height=2cm]{SE_5wg_REG_TURBz}
        \caption{Subgrid turbulent viscosity ratio [kg/m.s] - 5-wheels geometry close-up}
        \medskip
    \end{subfigure}\hfill
    \begin{subfigure}[t]{.49\textwidth} 
        \includegraphics[width=\textwidth,height=2cm]{SE_6wg_REG_TURBz}
        \caption{Subgrid turbulent viscosity ratio [kg/m.s] - 6-wheels geometry close-up}
        \medskip
    \end{subfigure}  \\
  \end{minipage}}
\caption{Influence of the solid exits: 5-wheels geometry (left) and 6-wheels geometry (right)}
\label{solid_exits}
\end{table}


\FloatBarrier\clearpage
\section{Influence of chimneys}
%Chimneys as turbulence creators?
%Chimney diameter? => central reflux! show in both 5wg and 6wg!
%Possible solution => conic chimneys, show with 6wg.

\begin{table}[htp]
\centering
\makebox[\textwidth][c]{%
  \begin{minipage}{1.4\textwidth}
    \begin{subfigure}[t]{.49\textwidth} 
        \includegraphics[width=\textwidth,height=2cm]{CH_5wg_REG_VV}
        \caption{In-plane velocity vectors [m/s] - 5-wheels geometry}
        \medskip
    \end{subfigure}
    \begin{subfigure}[t]{.49\textwidth} 
        \includegraphics[width=\textwidth,height=2cm]{CH_6wg_REG_VV}
        \caption{In-plane velocity vectors [m/s]] - 6-wheels geometry}
        \medskip
    \end{subfigure}     \\
    \begin{subfigure}[t]{.49\textwidth} 
        \includegraphics[width=\textwidth,height=2cm]{CH_5wg_REG_VVz2}
        \caption{In-plane velocity vectors [m/s] - 5-wheels geometry close-up}
        \medskip
    \end{subfigure}
    \begin{subfigure}[t]{.49\textwidth} 
        \includegraphics[width=\textwidth,height=2cm]{CH_6wg_REG_VVz2}
        \caption{In-plane velocity vectors [m/s] - 6-wheels geometry close-up}
        \medskip
    \end{subfigure}  \\
    \begin{subfigure}[t]{.49\textwidth} 
        \includegraphics[width=\textwidth,height=2cm]{CH_5wg_REG_AXIz}
        \caption{Axial velocity contours [m/s] - 5-wheels geometry close-up}
        \medskip
    \end{subfigure}
    \begin{subfigure}[t]{.49\textwidth} 
        \includegraphics[width=\textwidth,height=2cm]{CH_6wg_REG_AXIz}
        \caption{Axial velocity contours [m/s] - 6-wheels geometry close-up}
        \medskip
    \end{subfigure}  \\
    \begin{subfigure}[t]{.49\textwidth} 
        \includegraphics[width=\textwidth,height=2cm]{CH_5wg_REG_TURBz2}
        \caption{Subgrid turbulent viscosity ratio [kg/m.s] - 5-wheels geometry close-up}
        \medskip
    \end{subfigure}
    \begin{subfigure}[t]{.49\textwidth} 
        \includegraphics[width=\textwidth,height=2cm]{CH_6wg_REG_TURBz2}
        \caption{Subgrid turbulent viscosity ratio [kg/m.s] - 6-wheels geometry close-up}
        \medskip
    \end{subfigure}  \\
  \end{minipage}}
\caption{Influence of the chimneys: 5-wheels geometry (left) and 6-wheels geometry (right)}
\label{chimneys}
\end{table}

\end{document}
```

In the example, I used `height=2cm` in order not to get too large floats.

[image]

Comment: That's strange, why wouldn't it reset with tabularx?

Comment: @Romain That's what happens.

Comment: @Romain probably one of the packages uses primitive counter arithmetic rather than latex counter commands (in which case they may not get reset during tabularx trials) but as egreg says, tabularx is no use at all for this layout in any case.

Comment: Ok I redid my tables without tabularx and now it works :D. Thx!

Answer (score 0):

As discover @egreg, source of problem is `tabularx` If you use `tabular` instead it, all works as expected. See code below.

To have figures wider as it is text width, I suggest you to use `changepage` package. I include this option into my MWE:

```
\documentclass[11pt,oneside]{book}%{Thesis} % The default font size and one-sided printing
%\usepackage{showframe} % for demo

%\graphicspath{{./Pictures/}} % Specifies the directory where pictures are stored
    \usepackage{lmodern}
    \usepackage[T1]{fontenc}
    \usepackage{microtype}
    \usepackage[square, numbers, comma, sort&compress]{natbib}
    \usepackage[english]{babel}

    \usepackage[strict]{changepage}
    \usepackage{lipsum}

    \usepackage{mathtools}  % loads »amsmath«
    \usepackage{amsmath}
%\usepackage{physics}

    \usepackage{tabularx}
    \usepackage{multirow}
    \usepackage{booktabs}
    \usepackage[table]{xcolor}
%    \usepackage{adjustbox}

    \usepackage{ragged2e}
%    \usepackage{lua-visual-debug}

    \usepackage{float}
    \usepackage{placeins}
    \usepackage{graphicx}
    \usepackage{caption}
    \usepackage{subcaption}

    \usepackage{hyperref}
\hypersetup{urlcolor=blue,colorlinks=true} % Colors hyperlinks in blue - change to black if annoying
%\title{\ttitle} % Defines the thesis title - don't touch this

\begin{document}

\FloatBarrier
\section{Influence of solid exits}
%compare 5wg and 6wg. REG and SIDE sections, velocity vectors, turbulence, velocity contours?, ... Explain "vortex air-wall" in both, and why it's a clear advantage in 6wg.

\begin{table}[hbt]
\begin{adjustwidth*}{-21mm}{}
\begin{tabular}{@{}>{\raggedright\arraybackslash}p{0.49\linewidth}
                   >{\raggedleft \arraybackslash}p{0.49\linewidth}@{}}   
   \begin{subfigure}{\hsize}
    \includegraphics[width=\hsize,height=17mm]{example-image}
    \caption{In-plane velocity vectors [m/s] - 5-wheels geometry}
    \medskip
\end{subfigure}
&      \begin{subfigure}{\hsize}
        \includegraphics[width=\hsize,height=17mm]{example-image}
        \caption{In-plane velocity vectors [m/s]] - 6-wheels geometry}
        \medskip
    \end{subfigure}     \\
   \begin{subfigure}{\hsize}
        \includegraphics[width=\hsize,height=17mm]{example-image}
        \caption{In-plane velocity vectors [m/s] - 5-wheels geometry close-up}
        \medskip
    \end{subfigure}
&   \begin{subfigure}{\hsize}
        \includegraphics[width=\hsize,height=17mm]{example-image}
        \caption{In-plane velocity vectors [m/s] - 6-wheels geometry close-up}
        \medskip
    \end{subfigure}  \\
   \begin{subfigure}{\hsize}
        \includegraphics[width=\hsize,height=17mm]{example-image}
        \caption{Tangential velocity contours [m/s] - 5-wheels geometry close-up}
        \medskip
    \end{subfigure}
&   \begin{subfigure}{\hsize}
        \includegraphics[width=\hsize,height=17mm]{example-image}
        \caption{Tangential velocity contours [m/s] - 6-wheels geometry close-up}
        \medskip
    \end{subfigure}  \\
   \begin{subfigure}{\hsize}
        \includegraphics[width=\hsize,height=17mm]{example-image}
        \caption{Subgrid turbulent viscosity ratio [kg/m.s] - 5-wheels geometry close-up}
        \medskip
    \end{subfigure}
&   \begin{subfigure}{\hsize}
        \includegraphics[width=\hsize,height=17mm]{example-image}
        \caption{Subgrid turbulent viscosity ratio [kg/m.s] - 6-wheels geometry close-up}
        \medskip
    \end{subfigure}  
\end{tabular}
\end{adjustwidth*}
\caption{Influence of the solid exits: 5-wheels geometry (left) and 6-wheels geometry (right)}
\label{solid_exits}
\end{table}

    \lipsum[1]

\FloatBarrier
\section{Influence of chimneys}
%Chimneys as turbulence creators?
%Chimney diameter? => central reflux! show in both 5wg and 6wg!
%Possible solution => conic chimneys, show with 6wg.

\begin{table}[h]
\begin{adjustwidth*}{-21mm}{}
\begin{tabular}{@{}>{\raggedright\arraybackslash}p{0.49\linewidth}
                   >{\raggedleft \arraybackslash}p{0.49\linewidth}@{}}
        \begin{subfigure}{\hsize}
            \includegraphics[width=\hsize,height=17mm]{example-image}
            \caption{In-plane velocity vectors [m/s] - 5-wheels geometry}
            \medskip
        \end{subfigure}
&   \begin{subfigure}{\hsize}
        \includegraphics[width=\hsize,height=17mm]{example-image}
        \caption{In-plane velocity vectors [m/s]] - 6-wheels geometry}
        \medskip
    \end{subfigure}     \\
\begin{subfigure}{\hsize}
    \includegraphics[width=\hsize,height=17mm]{example-image}
    \caption{In-plane velocity vectors [m/s] - 5-wheels geometry close-up}
    \medskip
\end{subfigure}
&   \begin{subfigure}{\hsize}
        \includegraphics[width=\hsize,height=17mm]{example-image}
        \caption{In-plane velocity vectors [m/s] - 6-wheels geometry close-up}
        \medskip
    \end{subfigure}  \\
\begin{subfigure}{\hsize}
    \includegraphics[width=\hsize,height=17mm]{example-image}
    \caption{Axial velocity contours [m/s] - 5-wheels geometry close-up}
    \medskip
\end{subfigure}
&   \begin{subfigure}{\hsize}
        \includegraphics[width=\hsize,height=17mm]{example-image}
        \caption{Axial velocity contours [m/s] - 6-wheels geometry close-up}
        \medskip
    \end{subfigure}  \\
   \begin{subfigure}{\hsize}
    \includegraphics[width=\hsize,height=17mm]{example-image}
    \caption{Subgrid turbulent viscosity ratio [kg/m.s] - 5-wheels geometry close-up}
    \medskip
\end{subfigure}
&   \begin{subfigure}{\hsize}
        \includegraphics[width=\hsize,height=17mm]{example-image}
        \caption{Subgrid turbulent viscosity ratio [kg/m.s] - 6-wheels geometry close-up}
        \medskip
    \end{subfigure}
\end{tabular}
\caption{Influence of the chimneys: 5-wheels geometry (left) and 6-wheels geometry (right)}
\label{chimneys}
\end{adjustwidth*}
\end{table}
    \end{document}
```

Instead of `Thesis` I use `book`. I'm pretty sure that use of `Thesis` will change figure below.

[image]